# Как получать и изменять переменные из другого файла. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, переменные, ini

У меня есть 2 файла.
Помогите пожалуйста, мне надо сделать так, чтобы первый файл main.py брал переменные из второго файла second.py.

К примеру в файле second.py будет код:

```
x = 1
```

В файле main.py будет такой код:

```
x +=1
print(x)
```

И вывод будет сначала 2, а в файле second.py код будет уже `x = 2`
В следующий раз, при запуске main.py вывод будет 3, и во втором файле будет `x = 3`
и т.д.

Нужно это для того, чтобы если при перезапуске main.py, значения не сбрасывались. Я не знаю корректно ли я задал вопрос. Если буду нужен, пожалуйста напишите

Comment: так нельзя. но вы можете читать файл, менять содержимое и перезаписывать. В том числе это может быть и питоновский файл. Но менять в нем переменные так, как вы показали, нельзя

Comment: Для вас x это не код, а данные для хранения. Данные можете хранить в отдельном файле, например txt, JSON и тд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('second.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = f.readline()
b = int(a)
b+=1
print(b)
with open('second.txt', 'w+') as f:
    a = f.write(str(b))
```

данная программа полностью соответствует вашей задачи.

для этой задачи вам потребуется создать файл в формате **.txt** как у меня, по другому реализовать нельзя. можно, конечно, в формате **.py**, но смысла в это не так много, если у вас один файл чисто для хранения. проще хранить в текстовом формате

первый раз открывается файл для чтения, но открывается в формате строки. мы преобразуем его из формата **str** в **int**, чтобы могли сложить.

далее мы проверяем принтом, что все сложилось (данная строка не обязательна, чисто для проверки)

и в конце мы открываем файл в формате для записи, чтобы сохранить полученный результат.

после повторного запуска программа будет уже считать то число, что было получено в предыдущем запуске.

надеюсь все понятно объяснил. если что, то обращайтесь, объясню более подробно

```
with open('second.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read().split('\n')[0:2]    #позволяет читать каждую строку отдельно без лишних символов
q = []    #создаем временный файл, куда будем записывать полученные значения, чтобы они не удалились раньше времени
for i in range(len(a)):
    b = int(a[i])
    b+=1
    q.append(b)    #записываем полученное число во временный файл
print(str(q).replace(', ','\n')[1:-1])   #вывод без лишних знаков (построчно, вместо [2, 3])
with open('second.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for i in range(len(q)):    #перебором записываем в файл построчно
        a = f.write(f'{str(q[i])}\n')
```

как должен выглядеть при этом файл с данными:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Можете пожалуйста показать, как должен выглядеть этот код, к примеру если будет две переменные 'a 'и 'a1'.

Comment: @loganag Готово. Если коротко, то мы перебором каждое значение берем и складываем. Остальное описал в коде все. Это ведь надо было вам?

Comment: Спасибо. Помогли.

Comment: @loganag Если не сложно и правда помог, то отметите как решение, буду благодарен)

Answer (score 1):

можно и так написать.

```
from second import x
x+=1
print(x)
b = 'x ='
b=(b + str(x))
with open('second.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(b)
```